# melt [data.table] parameter patterns and environments

Tags: r, data.table

I wrote a R script using the data.table melt function, and the patterns parameter. To get the patterns, I use a variable. If I use it in a script outside of a function, everything is working as expected. If I use it in a script inside a function, there's an error, indicating that the object called in the function is not not found. However If I define it in the global env, the function works !

I was wondering if somebody knows why the variable need to be defined in the global env instead of the function env ?

```
require(data.table)

DT <- structure(list(family_id = 1:5, age_mother = c(30L, 27L, 26L, 32L, 29L), 
                 dob_child1 = c("26/11/1998", "22/06/1996", "11/07/2002", "10/10/2004", "05/12/2000"), 
                 dob_child2 = c("29/01/2000", NA, "05/04/2004", "27/08/2009", "28/02/2005"), 
                 dob_child3 = c(NA,  NA, "02/09/2007", "21/07/2012", NA), 
                 gender_child1 = c(1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 2L), 
                 gender_child2 = c(2L, NA, 2L, 1L, 1L), 
                 gender_child3 = c(NA, NA, 1L, 1L, NA)), 
            .Names = c("family_id", "age_mother", "dob_child1", "dob_child2", "dob_child3", "gender_child1", "gender_child2", "gender_child3"), 
            row.names = c(NA, -5L), 
            class = c("data.table", "data.frame"))

transpose_col <- "(^dob)|(^gender)"

# Works without problem.
melt(DT,
 measure = patterns(unlist(strsplit(gsub("\\(|\\)", "", transpose_col), "\\|"))), 
 value.name = unlist(strsplit(gsub("\\(|\\)|\\^", "", transpose_col), "\\|")))

# Bug:
in_local_env <-  function(DT) {
    transpose_col2 <- transpose_col
    melt(DT,
         measure = patterns(unlist(strsplit(gsub("\\(|\\)", "", transpose_col2), "\\|"))), 
         value.name = unlist(strsplit(gsub("\\(|\\)|\\^", "", transpose_col2), "\\|")))
}
in_local_env(DT) # generate an error.

in_global_env <- function(DT) {
    transpose_col3 <<- transpose_col
    transpost_col4 <- transpose_col
    melt(DT,
         measure = patterns(unlist(strsplit(gsub("\\(|\\)", "", transpose_col3), "\\|"))), 
         value.name = unlist(strsplit(gsub("\\(|\\)|\\^", "", transpost_col4), "\\|")))
}
in_global_env(DT) # Works as expected.
```

If I in_local_env debug the function and execute line by line, the melt won't work while the `unlist(strsplit(gsub("\\(|\\)", "", transpose_col), "\\|"))` will be executed whitout a problem.

I use data.table 1.9.6

Comment: `data.table` has now version [1.10.4](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/data.table/index.html); please update & check if the problem still occurs

Comment: I found the error occurs in 1.9.6, but not in 1.10.4

Comment: Thanks, to both of you, nice to know that it's working on 1.10.4. However the prod server is in 1.9.6, and I can't change the version that easily. Anyway using a global defined variable, I have a running function, I was just wondering how/why this is working this way.